# Chrome Developer Console accessing jQuery scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I would love to know if using Chrome's Developer Tools Console tab, I can manually access the function scope handed to jQuery when document ready is called.

So for example, if I have the following HTML and Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Accessing jQuery scope via Developer Console</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var globalId = "awesomeApp";
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var id = "myAppId";
        this.id2 = "myAppId2";
    } );

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If I type 'globalId' into the Developer Console window it will output 'awesomeApp'.

Please could someone advise me if it's possible to manually reference the jQuery scope from the Developer Console window, ie the function handed to jQuery when $(document).ready is called.

So, based on the above code, if I type:

[theAnswerToMyQuestionScope].id it would output 'myAppId'
or
[theAnswerToMyQuestionScope[instance]].id2 it would output 'myAppId2'

Many thanks in advance for help provided.

Comment: No. But what you can do is setting either watch expressions or set break points look at the scope variables in the Sources tab.

Comment: Set breakpoint or add debuger statements inside functino. As you know, JavaScript has functional scope. Inside ready method you are running unnamed function, outside this function you and Google developers tools hasn't access to variabless from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the debugger stops at a breakpoint you are working in the current scope.

So if you set a break point inside a the anonymous function you can type commands in the console and work in the current scope.

i.e typing `[instance]].id2` in the console in that break point should output `myAppId2`

Comment: Hi raam86, thank you for your reply and your answer is for me the solution :-)